# Need help for grub error

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

good morning, I have an error that until now I have not found anything similar, yesterday I got tired of using Ubuntu and from my Windows 10 I deleted the Ubuntu partition and joined that free space with my Windows partition and today when I started the PC I got the typical grub rescue error and I started looking for how to solve it, I tried to put ls and select the partitions and it would be supposed that one of those would have to work and none of them worked, I found another method if that fails and it is putting set boot=(partition that tells you) and then set prefix=(partition that tells you)/boot/grub, after that put insmod normal, then it should let put normal again but instead it puts a partition error and I have not found any solution to that. I've also tried inserting a USB booted with Windows 10 and booting from there, doing so only flashes a dash on the screen
The problem is that I want to access my Windows again and I can't (or I don't know how) due to the problems that I have already mentioned, please help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's ok, yesterday I deleted Ubuntu from the same PC in Windows, deleting the partition where it was installed, today when I started the PC it appeared (error: no such partition) (entering recue mode) and then grab recue.  Now the problem is that I can't (or don't know how) to access my Windows in any way since I tried the method of selecting the partitions through ls and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/1715254/how-to-format-pc)