# How to format PC?

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub

I have a problem with my pc, it has to do with the grub error and it does not find any partition. Here you can see how it does not detect any partition:

[image]

I have also tried to reinstall Windows from a booted USB but the pc does not react when I select it in the boot menu. When I select the first one, the first image appears and in the second one, which is where the Windows booted USB is then a screen appears with only a dash flashing:

[image]

Is there any way to format my pc without accessing it?

I just want to access my Windows and finally use it, I have also tried to get into the bios but there is no option that allows me to do that

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What does it mean to format a PC without accessing it?

Comment: 1. `<Enter Setup>` == BIOS. 2. Your `USB` might either be broken or have content that isn't bootable / complete. 3. Are you aware that reinstalling will erase any data you have?

Comment: Limit yourself to ONE question about a single issue - please delete this one; https://superuser.com/questions/1715230/need-help-for-grub-error

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader